# e-mail IsBodyHtml=false without urls or mailto

Tags: c#, email, encoding

I am sending an email with System.Net.Mail and I want to protect my user from receiving urls through those emails.
I have already used HtmlEncode and it works if my form data is html or script but if the user types a normal url (e.g. www.stackoverflow.com) or an email address, the e-mail body itself creates a link - even though I set IsBodyHtml to false.

I would like to know how I could ensure that my entire email body text cannot be clicked and taken somewhere else.

Ps: I tried using UrlEncode but it 'breaks' the entire email message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the email client (Outlook, Gmail, etc.) parsing the URL for your convenience. If you look inside the Body property of the MailMessage object, you would have no HTML link `(<a href=...)`.